# How to call Exelis ENVI tools with python and ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, envi

I am writing a script for geopocessing landsat data using ArcGIS 10.3. But ArcGIS doesn't have tools for landsat calibration (converting from DN to reflectance) and ENVI have this tool called "Radiometric calibration".

There is a way to call Exelis ENVI 5.2 tools using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support's answer:

> The Radiometric calibration tool is not available by default but you
>   can write your own script using ENVI+IDL and then create a python
>   script to call it.  Steps for creating a custom tool in ArcGIS can be
>   found in the "Tools for ArcToolbox" documentation and is also
>   discussed in [this whitepaper](http://www.exelisvis.com/Learn/WhitepapersDetail/TabId/802/ArtMID/2627/ArticleID/9895/ENVI-Tools-for-ArcGIS174-and-ENVI-for-ArcGIS174-Server.aspx).

In fact this whitepaper is general tutorial for creating such tool.
Detailed tutorial you can find in ENVI help file `enviforarcgis.chm`, see page `Authoring Custom Tools Tutorial` (only true for ver. 5.0 - help manual have changed in ENVI 5.2 version)

[image]